# usage of maven-dependency-plugin on dependencyManagement

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use the `maven-depdency-plugin` to list the dependencies, declared in a `dependencyManagement` section of the POM.

Example :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeTypes>war</excludeTypes>
                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>list</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>list</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sort>true</sort>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/dependencies.txt</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when i run `mvn validate`, the generated file is empty :

```
The following files have been resolved:
   none
```

The plugin only works for the `dependencies` section of the POM ?